# How to send fetch requests after getting a response from the previous request in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, get

I have a variable `details` which needs to be filled by a sending a get request to '/abc'. After which I need to access the values in the `details` variable to send other requests to '/def'.

I am unable to understand how would I do that.

I have two separate functions which I am using. First is `updateDetails()` which updates the `details` state, and I call it in `componentDidMount()`. Second method is `sendOtherRequests()` which I need to call after the `details` has all the values.

The issue is that I added both the functions in `componentDidMount()` but since they are asynchronous calls, it didn't work as calls were made before `details` was completely filled in.

My code looks something like this:

```js
updateDetails = () => {
    ...get('abc')
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          details: data
        })
      })
  }
```

```js
sendOtherRequests = () => {
   
   for(let i in details) {
    ...get('def/' + i)
      .then(res => {
        // save data
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('error caught ' + JSON.stringify(err))
        return false
      })
   }
  }
```

I would appreciate any help. I am bit new with React.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data required to send requests in `sendOtherRequests` will be available  in the **then block** of `get('abc')`.Try calling `sendOtherRequests` there.

```
updateDetails = () => {
    ...get('abc')
      .then(data => {
        ...your code
        sendOtherRequests()
      })
  }
```

Comment: I am a bit new to React and this fetch request in general, so please correct me if I am wrong. fetch requests are asynchronous so if even if I call inside the `then()` clause will the `details` variable really filled?

Comment: When you do any fetch request, it returns promise.Promise can be in any of states like pending,completed,rejected.So if promise is pending and resolved after sometime you will get data. then block is where your data will be available after promise got resolved.

Comment: hey @Panda did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

try with this hope this will work for you .

```
updateDetails = () => {
    ...get('abc')
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          details: data
        },()=>{
             someOtherRequests()
              })
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give a callback to your setState i.e. when state is updated, you can call your other request:

```js
updateDetails = () => {
    ...get('abc')
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          details: data
        }, sendOtherRequests)
      })
  }
```